# Negative Margins are not working in TMS WEB Core

Tags: delphi, margin, tms, tms-web-core

In FireMonkey you can set negative `Margins` and you can use this to let components overlap such as this:

[image: Overlapping circles]

But when I try to set negative `Margins` in TMS WEB Core, then I get an error. It seems like you can't set negative `Margins`:

> Value must be between 0 and 2147483647.

[image: Delphi Error - Value must be between 0 and 2147483647.]

Is there any way around this? Why can't I have negative `Margins`?

How can I create a UI in Delphi like the screenshot above with the circles?

Comment: Hi Shaun, I do not use TMS Components at the moment, but I have in the past. Addressing your question on https://support.tmssoftware.com will lead to a faster answer, than on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks @fisi-pjm. I don't have access to the TMS Support Website. The Support Website is only available to licensed users. I'm currently just playing with the trial versions of TMS components. So StackOverflow is what I got 

Comment: You're definitly not playing. Assign negative values CSS wise and stop insisting on component properties. Even without margins overlapping elements are possible in various ways.

Comment: @AmigoJack I don't actually care how it's done. You're welcome to write an answer. Any way to achieve it is welcome. It doesn't have to be via component properties.

Comment: I won't write `.ElementHandle.style.setProperty( 'margin-left', '-5px' )` in its own answer because it's again simple CSS knowledge. In your question you neither confirmed nor denied trying it, but just stopping at the component's property while knowing what is possible and not adapting to dozens of `.ElementHandle` "answers" before would be silly.